# How to go back using an intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new to android.
I have a code(intent) that takes me to the homescreen when the button is pressed...

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startMain);
```

Likewise i want to go back using an intent..
Please help ME!

Comment: pressing back button will do the job if you want to navigate to previous activity

Comment: finish() to close the current activity and go back.

Comment: I want to press the back button Programmatically!

Comment: finish() doesnt work...and i want an intent to get back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your activity where you want to use back button pragmatically ,override back button as follow :

```
        @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
         // code here to show dialog
         super.onBackPressed();  // optional depending on your needs

finish();
    }
```

then call this method from anywhere you want to back pragmatically like as follow :

```
onBackPressed();
```

Comment: But onBackPressed(); doesnot take me back...instead monitors my back presses!

Comment: it back button necessary to go back ? you can finish activity onButton Click by calling finish() method ?